# Internet Explorer 8 and Checkbox CSS Problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm currently having problems with Internet Explorer 8 ignoring padding/line-heights that I have on a list which includes a check box.

To start off here is my CSS and XHTML markup [here](http://www.users.on.net/~prashyanthy/text.html), the issue occurs with the list element which includes **Private**.

At the moment Firefox 3, Internet Explorer 7, Safari 3, Google Chrome renders this list perfectly, [screenshot](http://www.users.on.net/~prashyanthy/perfect.jpg) here. But this is how Internet Explorer 8 renders the list, [screenshot](http://www.users.on.net/~prashyanthy/notperfect.jpg) here.

Can anyone suggest a method to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just had a look at the same issue occurs in Opera! Arggg!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also once having some problems with IE8. So, I declared a different doctype and it worked!!

Currently, you are suing xhtml transitional.

Try this:(ok, edited)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

read more about doctypes and how can they fix sites here:
[A list apart-Fix your site with right doctype](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)

Comment: This fixed it but broke the rest of my site :/

Is there any ideas to why this is occuring CSS wise?

Comment: Well it should really be XHTML 1.0 Strict, since you're using XHTML syntax not HTML4. Either way, Strict/Transitional normally switches between full Standards and “Almost Standards” mode; there is not usually much difference. The curious thing is that your transitional doctype should have left you in Almost Standards mode, which is closer to what IE7 did than full Standards.

Comment: Setting it back to strict fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
// fix for ie8 printed checkbox bug using jquery
$('input[type=checkbox]').live('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[IE8 checkbox not printing bug fix using jQuery](http://leewaterman.com/ie8-checkbox-not-printing-bug-fix-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in IE (and Opera as it happens) the checkbox doesn't participate in the inline content of the li, so, since the label doesn't either because it's floated, the line-height setting for the li has no effect.

Add a &nbsp; after the label in the checkbox line, and that will be sufficient for the line-height to take effect, and all the li s will be the same height.

Answer (score 0):

My limited experience with IE8 so far has been that it's very picky about proper markup.  Accordingly, you've got a close tag with no corresponding head.  Check that out and see if it helps.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.users.on.net%2F~prashyanthy%2Ftext.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Fixing this made no changes to the issue.