# How does Almost Standards Mode change rendering from Standards mode?

Tags: html, css

All the documentation I can find suggests that almost standards mode differs from standards mode only in the way images in table cells are aligned.

This question : [Internet Explorer 8 and Checkbox CSS Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414748/internet-explorer-8-and-checkbox-css-problem), however indicates that the rendering in IE8 and Opera changed between the two modes, based on how checkboxes are interpreted. Certainly there are neither tables nor images on that page.

So, does anyone know of other differences between these two modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it removes [baseline under inline images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps) which are only child of their containers.

[MDC reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20210514021827/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko_Almost_Standards_Mode).

Comment: And it seems some other inline elements have the same effect. Certainly `iframe` and `canvas` are treated the same way as `img`.

Answer (score 2):

The [original almost standards mode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/24/almost-target/) only affected images in tables. Other browsers adopting the mode may of course have put other differences in it.

Form fields, and especially checkboxes, are tricky. The standards doesn't really cover how they should be rendered, so it's still pretty much up to the browser to make something reasonable out of it. Checkboxes are inline elements just like images, so some browsers may very well handle them similar to images.

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft article explains the difference and covers both the common case of images and baselines, as well as the behaviour of checkboxes that prompted this question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405794%28v=vs.85%29

It says that for Almost Standards mode:

> Inline elements contribute to line height if and only if one of the
>   following is true.
>
> If the element:
>
> - Contains text characters
> - Has a nonzero border width
> - Has a nonzero margin
> - Has a nonzero padding
> - Has a background image
> - Has vertical-align set to a value other than baseline
>
> Note that a line break is not considered a text character for this
>   definition unless it is the only content of a line box. In that case,
>   the line box height remains the uppermost inline box top and the
>   lowermost inline box bottom on the line, regardless of the specified
>   line height.
>
> If an img element is the sole content of a table cell, the line box
>   height of the cell line box height is adjusted to zero.