# Primefaces checkbox consistency across browsers

Tags: css, checkbox, primefaces, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem when checking/unchecking a checkbox under internet explorer 8.

When I check a checkbox, it "moves" vertically, then it returns in the original position when I uncheck it.
I tried to figure it out playing with margin and vertical-align, but with no luck.

The code work flawlessly in Firefox and Chrome.

Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition template="../templates/ui-test.xhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:nttdata="http://nttdata.com/facelets" lang="it-IT">

  <ui:define name="title">Test Checkbox</ui:define>

  <ui:define name="head"></ui:define>

  <ui:define name="navbar"></ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
    <div id="contentCc">
      <h:outputText value="Selection: " />
      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testViewBean.selectedValue}" />
    </div>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
  lang="it-IT">

  <f:view contentType="text/html" locale="it_IT">

  <h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv='Cache-control' content='no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' />
      <meta http-equiv='Expires' content='0' />
      <meta http-equiv='Pragma' content='no-cache' />
      <title>
        <ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert>
      </title>
    </f:facet>

    <ui:insert name="head"></ui:insert>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="header" class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <ui:insert name="navbar">
          <ui:include 
            src="#{pageContext.request.contextPath}/components/navbar/navbar.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
      </div> <!-- header -->

      <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Default Content</ui:insert>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <!--ui:insert name="footer"></ui:insert-->
      </div>
  </div> <!-- outer -->
  </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

The resulting XHTML code is valid (validated with validator.w3.org), but under ie8 the input element "dance" when clicked. Here are the images of checked and unchecked checkbox under ie8:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7865852/ie8_checkbox_unchecked.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7865852/ie8_checkbox_checked.png

Using **h**:selectBooleanCheckbox instead of **p**:selectBooleanCheckbox works under ie8, but I lose all the (framework default) css styles applied.

Comment: Someone had a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414748/internet-explorer-8-and-checkbox-css-problem), maybe that will help you.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy, the page is now XHTML valid, but checkboxes on ie8 do not render properly.

Comment: It is a Primefaces bug, see: [http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=36270](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=36270).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but with all the browser (primefaces 5.1)
I fixed it with css on checkbox elements

```
display: block;
float: left;
```